# Implicit conversion from data type datetime to timestamp is not allowed

Tags: sql-server, datetime

The error message:

> Implicit conversion from data type datetime to timestamp is not allowed

The C# `dateTime` definition:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Calling SQL Server stored procedure with `DateTime` parameter (from C#):

```
   sqlCommand.CommandText = "dbo.StoredPrcoName";
   sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
   sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", dateTime);
```

I get in SQL Server:

```
@BirthDate datetime  = NULL,
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Show the rest of the SP

Comment: Note that the SQL Server `timestamp` data type is unrelated to date or time; it's a `rowversion` for optimistic concurrency checking. Perhaps you've inadvertently used it in your proc or database schema instead of `datetime` or `datetime2`.

Comment: Yes, Tim beat me to it.  You have to show us the procedure how you are processing the `dateTime` alias `11.05.2018 11:38:37`.

Comment: `timestamp` is the deprecated name of the [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) type. It's *not* date/time related. The date types are `date`, `datetime`, `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset`. You'll have to *change* the field type if it was added in error, or add a new field with the appropriate type.

Comment: Lastly - don't use [addwithvalue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Time to start using best practices in your code.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Server `timestamp` data type is unrelated to date or time; `timestamp` is a poorly named legacy synonym for [`rowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql), an automatically incremented value used for optimistic concurrency checking.

The error message indicates you have inadvertently used `timestamp` it in your stored procedure or database schema instead of `datetime` or `datetime2`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into the stored procedure for what i have miss.